# Keyword Metadata Translation?

Tags: translation-manager

Publication settings for Translation Manager (Connector) to SDL WorldServer or TMS include an option for `Keywords` and other items (building blocks).

**Can I turn this setting on, send Keyword metadata for translation, but somehow exclude the Keyword name (title) visible in the Content Manager Explorer from translation?**

I want the Keywords to appear in their source language for authors across the BluePrint, while a separate field (`description` or metadata) will hold translations in child publications.

Comment: For us the keyword name is getting translated, We have selected the keyword description check box not the keyword name check box in publication properties and also where is the settings to translate keyword metadata? I have selected the translatable check box in the keyword metadata schema but still it is not getting translated.

Comment: StackExchange is a Q&A site, not a forum. So unfortunately it is not really ment to ask additional questions like you did now. Your post is made as an answer to the original question - and as it does not actually answer anything that was asked it is not going to be considered a good post. You can either post a new question, or leave comment to existing questions or answers

Comment: Jag, I converted your question to a comment. Do ask it in a new Question, I'm sure you'll get at least one good answer if tagged appropriately. :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the properties of the Source Publication you can choose to translate the Name or Description of the keyword or both.

[image]

Just choose to translate the description, so the name will appear in the original language.
Haven't tried but that is the direction I would follow

Based on the documentation

http://sdllivecontent.sdl.com/LiveContent/web/pub.xql?c=t&action=home&pub=SDL%20Tridion%20full%20documentation-v1&lang=en-US#url=/LiveContent/web/search.xql%3Fc%3Dt%26pub%3DSDL+Tridion+full+documentation-v1%26lang%3Den-US%26action%3Dsearch%26query%3Dmobile&sid=lcSearch.runSearch1409854598719&currentQuery=mobile&currentScope=&eventType=lcContent.loadDocGUID-5987B065-A251-4CC5-A08A-7FE50F5D4648&query=&scope=&filename=GUID-5987B065-A251-4CC5-A08A-7FE50F5D4648.xml&docid=GUID-5987B065-A251-4CC5-A08A-7FE50F5D4648&inner_id=&tid=&addHistory=true&resource=&toc=false

The Metadata always will be translated