# How are metadata fields translated?

Tags: web8.5, cme, translation-manager

I have a page with some metadata text fields that are marked as translatable. I cannot translate metadata separately because they are not components. I also cannot select if metadata will be sent to translation because there is no option in translation settings UI for it:
[image]

So my question is: **Is metadata sent directly with the items OOTB to translation?**

Comment: May be this will give you some idea https://tridion.stackexchange.com/questions/7817/keyword-metadata-translation

Comment: Marko - are you saying that the metadata fields you have now are _not_ being sent for translation?

If this is the case - can you ensure you make an update before testing and/or check the box to force a translation even if TMS detects no changes since the last translation version was sent.

Comment: No no, just wanted to verify if that is the case. Because it seems like they are sent by default if fields are checked as translatable in schema. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, if configured, Metadata fields are sent to translation out-of-the-box.

Per the [Documentation](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v5/GUID-EAB21D5C-C4AE-4C5B-8C33-6D7D0F7CEB06):

> You can control which Text fields and External Link fields are sent for translation in Schemas by selecting the Translatable check box in:
>
> - Schema fields
> - Embeddable Schema fields
> - Schema metadata fields
> - Multimedia Schema metadata fields
> - Metadata Schema fields
> - Bundle Schema metadata fields

The [Translatable Content topic](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v5/GUID-5987B065-A251-4CC5-A08A-7FE50F5D4648) covers the translateable item types, which includes text, rich text, and external link fields:

> ### Translatable Metadata fields
>
> If the following Content Manager items have metadata fields of type Text field, External Link field or Format Area field, you can send these fields for translation:
>
> - Components
> - Multimedia Components
> - Folders
> - Structure Groups
> - Pages
> - Keywords
> - Bundles
> - Virtual Folders

Having noted this, keep in mind that though using Page metadata specifically for translateable content is indeed a supported feature, this reduces centralized control over a Page's Component Presentations.

See [Manuel Garrido's thought leadership on minimizing localizations](http://tridionstrategist.blogspot.com/p/sdl-tridion-blueprint-minimizing.html) or his post on [BluePrinting and translation](http://tridionstrategist.blogspot.com/p/sdl-tridion-blueprint-and-translation.html).